# Youtube audio has echo in Safari on macOS

Tags: macos, safari, audio

When watching YouTube videos I get a constant audio problems. The audio always sounds far off and it has a bit of echo to it. The problem is safari specific as the same videos work fine in another browser. Anybody know what is causing this and how to fix it?

**EDIT:** The problem appears to occur only when the videos are played at anything other than 1.0x speed.

I'm using safari 10.1.1

Answer (score 1):

It's an old bug in Safari, and it is still present. If it really annoys you, the only suggestion I can come up with is to use Chrome as an alternative.

[Link to reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/OSXElCapitan/comments/3kcqnv/youtube_speed_increase_audio_bug_on_safari/)